# Blender 2.8 Export to FBX not available

Tags: export, .fbx

I am using Blender 2.8 Alpha 2 and enabled the FBX export add-on.
However I cannot seem to export to FBX there is no such option?

How can I export my blender model to FBX using 2.8 Alpha 2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished experimental development software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of addons are disabled because Python API will change. Python API will be freeze after beta release (end of October), and it will take some time to update addons to new API.

Comment: thank you, I will set a reminder for the end of October.

Comment: You need to know, that Python API freeze will not be right after beta release